# How to do a complete start over in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, migration

I have a neighbor who had a Magento 2 site made that is really buggy. The developer lives in another country and won't fix it without further payment. The whole thing seems a bit scammy to me and I would like to help her.

How can I plan a starting over from scratch considering what we have today?

How could we do that?

Answer (score 0):

**Least Destructive:**

First thing I'd do is evaluate the site and find out what functionality your neighbor needs, and what of that is "custom". Then determine what extensions need to stay to achieve that functionality. I'd remove anything else that isn't necessary and clean up any lingering database tables.

For the theme, you can start over from scratch using Luma as a base. You can then scrap the old theme if it's not necessary anymore.

**Nuclear Option:**

If they really don't care about customer data, sales data, products and categories, you can just follow the [Magento DevDocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/bk-install-guide.html) on starting a new project and start completely fresh.

You probably could export the product, category and customer data, but odds are it won't be perfect because the IDs might not match up. Add on to that you'll need to account for custom attributes for a data migration.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. It has been much appreciated